# Text wrap in position absolute follows edge of parent

Tags: html, css, css-position, w3c, word-wrap

I can't seem to find this in the specs.

When I position an element with `absolute` then text inside the element makes the element expand only until the edge of the positioned parent where the text then wraps (in Firefox 5).

This means that if I position anything off the right edge of its parent my text will wrap after every word.

Can anyone point me to where this is described?

Comment: Are you asking about this? http://jsfiddle.net/n7P46/

Comment: (Sorry, thought I'd be notified of replies!) Yes, that's exactly what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

```html
    <style type="text/css">
    #relative 
        {
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #ccc;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative
        }

    #relative > div 
        {
        background: #f0f;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 150px;
        }
    </style>
    <!--...-->
    <div id="relative">
        <div>text text text</div>
    </div>
```

Set the absolutely positioned div to `width: 100%;` or a fixed value to resolve the issue. It's described in the `normal flow` section of [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting).

```html
    <style type="text/css">
    #relative 
        {
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #ccc;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative
        }

    #relative > div 
        {
        background: #f0f;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 150px;
        width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <!--...-->
    <div id="relative">
        <div>text text text</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm talking about. Trying to understand this. How can it be avoided? Where is this behavior described?

Comment: Set `width: 100%;`. It's described in the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) section of the spec.